# the ASCII table symbols are not displayed

Tags: console, ascii, console-application

The console does not display characters from ASCII from 1 to 31, instead they display question marks in the rectangles. Tell me what to do, please

[image]

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<Windows.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<time.h>
int main()
{
const int startingMoney = 500;
const int turnCost = 50;
const int doubleBonus = 60;
const int tripleBobus = 100;
int money = startingMoney;
char panel0 = 'X';
char panel1 = 'X';
char panel2 = 'X';
srand(time(NULL));
do
{
    system("cls");
    printf("\n\n");
    printf("\t ######### \n");
    printf("\t# BANDITO #\n");
    printf("\t###########\n");
    printf("\t#         #\n");
    printf("\t#  %c %c %c  #\n", panel0, panel1, panel2);
    printf("\t#         #\n");
    printf("\t###########\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("\tMoney: %d$\n", money);
    _getch();
    money = money - turnCost;
    panel0 = 3 + (rand() % 4);
    panel1 = 3 + (rand() % 4);
    panel2 = 3 + (rand() % 4);
    if ((panel0 == panel1) && (panel0 == panel2))
    {
        money = money + tripleBobus;
    }
    if ((panel0 == panel1) || (panel0 == panel2) || panel1 == panel2)
    {
        money = money + doubleBonus;
    }
 } while (money >= turnCost);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Everything under 32 is either whitespace or unprintable control characters. What did you expect this to print, and why?

Comment: I expected the console to print characters ♥ ♦ ♣ ♠. But the problem has already been solved by adding the old version of the console

Comment: That looks like CP437, not ASCII.